# Statics HW Problem: determining magnitude and direction of resultant

Tags: statics

[image]

[image]

The above shows the question and my work. I am confused on why my original solution does not get me the correct answer

If I sum x + y + 35 = 40 + 75 + 35 = 150, I am not getting 180 degrees which tells me something is wrong with my diagram

Comment: I can't follow your working as the screenshots are unreadably small.  and badly explained. The actual solution you give is ludicrous, what is 30/17.8*sin(35)?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. The small stuff is not my work so just ignore it

Comment: Looking at the second paper though why does my original solution not work

Comment: I get a force of 17.8 at -5 degrees.

Comment: My first attempt led to -5 degrees. When you find the angle associated with the 20N force you get theta = 40, so to get the direction of R you would do 40-35 = 5

Comment: In my second attempt, which followed my professor’s solution, I found the angle associated with the 30N force which is 75, and to get the angle between the y axis and R I did 75-20 = 55 degrees. Because the x and y axes are perpendicular, to get the direction of R I did 90-55 = 35 which is what the solution says

Comment: Why do these two approaches lead to different results

Comment: I don't know, since I can't follow what you did in either case.